# Wiring up the MVVM View and ViewModel using Declarative DataContext for Design-Time and Data Template for Runtime?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datacontext, instantiation

Is it possible to wire up the View and ViewModel using both a Declarative DataContext and a Data Template?

**Goal**: I want to wire Views with a one ViewModel for design-time and another at run-time.  Currently, using a Declarative DataContext for a design-time VM and a Data-Template-specified VM for runtime doesn't behave as expected.

**Background** - There are a variety of ways to wire up a View and ViewModel including the following:

A.) ***Declaratively specify the ViewModel DataContext within the View’s XAML***.  This technique is useful at Design-Time using the parameter-less constructor to pass in dummy data.

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <my: BrowseAssetsViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

B.) ***Programmatically specify the ViewModel, View and DataContext***.

```
// …Setup code
BrowseAssetsViewModel viewModel = new BrowseAssetsViewModel(assetRegistry, domains);
BrowseAssetsView view = new BrowseAssetsView();
view.DataContext = viewModel;
```

When Approach B is used in combination with Approach A, at run-time WPF overrides the default DataContext specified in Approach A using the version of the ViewModel with the parameterized constructor specified in Approach B.

***C.) Define a Data Template for the View-ViewModel association***
By associating a View and ViewModel in App.XAML Application.Resources, WPF can wire up the correct View based on a ViewModel’s type.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm: BrowseAssetsViewModel }">
    <vw: BrowseAssetsView />
</DataTemplate>
```

If a ViewModel property were bound to a ContentPresenter control, WPF would wire-up the corresponding View (based on the ViewModel’s type) and place it within the ContentPresenter.  This is useful in the “ViewModel-first” scenario where the ViewModel is presented and WPF resolves and wires the correct View by inspecting the presented ViewModel’s type.

**Problem** - When using this Approach C in combination with Approach A, WPF resolves the correct View but it seems to then re-query the View, calling the declaratively specified ViewModel via the parameter-less constructor (Approach A), thus overriding the existing ViewModel property!

**Question - Is there a way to use these techniques (C and A) together without A inadvertently overwriting the C ViewModel property?**

Comment: Why would you declaratively specify a ViewModel's DataContext within the View’s XAML if you do not want that declaration to take place?

Comment: The goal is to find a technique that supports both a design-time dummy ViewModels (A) and DataTemplate resolution (C) at run-time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify that the DataContext is in case A set only only at *design time*, like so:

```
<UserControl ...
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance my:BrowseAssetsViewModel}"
>
```

For details, see [Using a DesignInstance...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd490796%28VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, add 'IsDesignTimeCreatable=True' so it shows up in VS.
For example, d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:BrowseAssetsViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"

Comment: This answer, combined with the IsDesignTimeCreatable=True mentioned in the comment solved the problem.  Thanks, both of you.  -Larry